# TensorFlow installation issue Mac

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow

I recently started google's machine learning crash course. However it didn't mention how to install TensorFlow, so I went to the website and followed the terminal instructions below for Mac.

```
$ virtualenv --system-site-packages -p python3 ./venv

$ source ./venv/bin/activate

(venv)$ pip install --upgrade pip

(venv)$ pip list

(venv)$ pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

This install step would return,

> Requirement already up-to-date: tensorflow in
>   ./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.12.0) Requirement already
>   satisfied, skipping upgrade: protobuf>=3.6.1 in
>   ./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tensorflow) (3.6.1)...

The next step was to test tensor flow in python,

```
(venv)$ python -c "import tensorflow as tf; tf.enable_eager_execution(); print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random_normal([1000, 1000])))"
```

However, this would return,

> RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 3.6 of module
>   'tensorflow.python.framework.fast_tensor_util' does not match runtime
>   version 3.7   return f(*args, **kwds) 2019-02-05 18:18:09.866187: I
>   tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports
>   instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
>   FMA tf.Tensor(-1912.4221, shape=(), dtype=float32)

I've tried to install it outside of the virtual environment but would receive another error.

```
$ pip3 install --user --upgrade tensorflow
```

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow
>   (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for tensorflow You
>   are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.0.1 is available. You
>   should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

I've tried a few other variations I found online but still got the same errors. The site I got the instructions on was, https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Tensorflow` doesn't work with `Python 3.7`, use `Python 3.6` instead.

Comment: Thanks, took me a while to do it but it solved the problem.